# Add Separator "-" in text field in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, separator

I would like to add "**-**" between 4 numbers when user is typing in **PinNo** text field. 
For example, **1234 - 5678 - 9932**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

// try like this

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool 
{
    var strText: String? = textField.text
   if strText == nil {
     strText = ""
   }
 strText = strText?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString:"")
 if strText!.characters.count > 1 && strText!.characters.count % 4 == 0 && string != "" {
    textField.text = "\(textField.text!)-\(string)"
     return false
 }

 return true
}
```

Comment: Error : value of type 'String?' has no member "characters" shows.

Comment: No error now. Spelling of "character" is wrong. Whatever thank you. :)

Comment: ohh, all the above code typed here only , okay fine i will edit that answer :), anyway is it working for you

Comment: not working well. When I type , it shows "Optional -\( 123" like that.

Comment: do one thing change this line like this textField.text = "\(textField.text)-\(string)" as textField.text = "\(textField.text!)-\(string)"

Comment: i edited the answer , take code from there , then it will work for u

Comment: Yes. It's working now. Thank you very much :). One more I want to add is that to remove "-" from beginning.

Comment: if strText!.characters.count != 0 {
             txtPinNo.text = "\(txtPinNo.text!)-\(string)"
            return false
            }

Comment: for this hyphen(-) is added for every charecter what you are typing

Comment: so, don't add if strText!.characters.count != 0 { txtPinNo.text = "(txtPinNo.text!)-(string)" return false }

Comment: for that i extended that condition with strText!.characters.count > 1 && so no issue, so that problem wont come now

Comment: once check the answer

Comment: It is working well now. Thanks a lot to you. :)

Comment: for swift 3 use  `strText?.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")` instead of `strText?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString:"")`